# Change keyboard repeat rate while a program is open (detect in bash script when a program starts/end)

Tags: bash

I have a problem with Terraria that requires me to set the repeat delay to a high value (game detects input as rapidy pressing keys rather than holding them down).

I can set the keyboard repeat rate but it would be quite annoying to change it every time I open and exit the game manually.

My idea of doing it would be writing a simple bash script that changes it once when the game starts, and when it stops, but a quick google search didn't tell me how to check when a program starts/stops in bash.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following shell script, make it executable (`chmod +x shell-script`) and launch the game with it.

```
xset r rate 300 100 #Here the delay and rate while game is open
launch-game         #Here the command to launch the game
xset r rate 300 25  #Here your normal delay and rate
```

Inspect your current rate with `xset q`.

You could make it more elaborate, getting the current auto-repeat delay and repeat rate automatically by parsing `xset q`, and giving the delay and rate as arguments (so you would run `shell-script 300 100` to set the delay to 300 and repeat rate to 100 during the game).

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# = 2 ] || { echo "I need two arguments."; exit 1; }
arr=($(xset q | sed -n '/auto repeat delay:/s/[^0-9]/ /gp'))
xset r rate "$1" "$2"
launch-game
xset r rate "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This did not work. The rate doesn't change when I open the program with either of the code posted above.

Comment: @HFEPK11111 But do you get any change when you run `xset r rate 300 100`? When you launch game from terminal, do you get the prompt back or does the terminal "hang"?

Comment: I don't get a prompt even when it does change. I still get the problem occuring, and using xset q it also doesn't seem to show any change.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is not clear. (1) You should get no prompt *until you close the game* if you run any of the shell scripts I provided. (2) A change in typing rate should be noticed if you issue `xset r rate 300 100` in the terminal, and you should get the prompt back instantly. (3) `xset q` should reflect the rates changed by the last issued `xset r rate ...`. Which of those do not occur in your system? If you receive an error message, report it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I think that this happens because I am launching the game through 'steam steam://rungameid/105600' which just tells steam to run it, ending the script early.

I am unsure as to how to run it manually.